# How to interpret parameters of FFmpeg's atadenoise filter in plain English?

Tags: ffmpeg, noise

I am experimenting with FFmpeg and its [atadenoise](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atadenoise) filter to remove grain from a video file in order to improve compressibility. The grain was artificially added for artistic reasons.

I am puzzled to understand the *atadenoise* parameters and what effect they have on the resulting output video. The documentation is very vague. Example:

```
0a - Set threshold A for 1st plane. Default is 0.02. Valid range is 0 to 0.3.
0b - Set threshold B for 1st plane. Default is 0.04. Valid range is 0 to 5.
...
```

**Q:** What are planes?

I have read the paper from Bartovcak/Vrankic but I do not see how those parameters [012]a and [012]b are derived from it. Thresholds are used in the text and in terms of video processing they are used to define two frames: one before and one after the current frame to do the averaging. Is that correct?

I played around with the parameters too see what they do. Observations:

- gently modified threshold values seem to reduce fine grain well (e.g. 0a=0.05, 0b=0.07)
- high values for 1st planes cause ghosting
- high values for 2nd and especially 3rd plane causes slight but weird color changes
- if threshold A >= B no denoising seems to be happening

**Q:** So in normal English, what do these values actually do? What will happen if I use a lower/value for 0a? Or for 0b?